# Number of distinct pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers such that $360(a+b) = ab$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers

Should I show that $a$ is less than or equal to $b$ by assuming a contradiction that $a>b$?

Comment: Not an answer, but it may be interesting to notice the equation can be rewritten $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{360}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ ab - 360 a - 360 b = 0  $$
$$ ab - 360 a - 360 b + 360^2 = 360^2  $$
$$ (a - 360) (b - 360) = 360^2  $$
Note that both factors could be positive or both factors negative.

Oh, I get it. If both negative, one of the factors, say $a - 360 \leq -360.$ Which would be fine, except they demand $a > 0.$ All this does, in the end, is cut the integer pairs in half. That is, if $(a,b)$ is an integer solution, so is $(720-a,720-b),$ because the product $(a-360)(b-360)$ is replaced by $(720-a - 360)(720- b - 360) = (360 - a)(360 - b).$ Symmetry of the hyperbola around its center.

Comment: Nice. And since $360^2=2^6\times3^4\times5^2$ has $7\times5\times3=105$ divisors, this is also the number of solutions with $a-360>0$ and $b-360>0$. If one wants $a<b$, there are only $52$ solutions (half of $104$, and the $105$th is $a=b=720$).